# API change the relationship status (Married, Single, etc)

Tags: facebook, api, relationship, status

Help. I need to know if you can change the relationship status (Married, Single, etc) from the facebook api. I get to read but not updated. The updating of the list would be done by an application in an iframe facebook.
Looking for google I find nothing that says you can not, nor find anything that says you can.
Thank you very much. (Sorry for my GoogleEnglish.i'm spanish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no profile data can be updated via the Facebook API unfortunately.